# How can i achieve truncated text in a responsive width table column?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a table with 4 columns. The second column displays an email address and i'd like that column to take up the maximum amount of width within the table that it can. Then when the viewport size becomes smaller, the column width should be responsive and the email displayed should truncate if it becomes too large for the column.

All the solutions i've found so far either use `table: {table-layout:fixed;}` or set a `max-width` value on the `td`. Which are no good for me as they force the columns to specific widths.

This is what i'm trying to achieve regarding the column width layout, but the truncation fails. I read on an SO comment (showing the `max-width` solution) that setting `width: 100%` and `min-width: 1px` would have the desired affect, but it doesn't appear to work.

http://plnkr.co/edit/gIC5u6wq6oCYhF5pCJJp?p=preview

This is a `max-width` example where at least the text truncates, but the column widths are wrong.

http://plnkr.co/edit/e8sj2iqRUpBytMomddCS?p=preview

I've also tried wrapping the email text in a `div`, setting the width of the `td` to 100% and then setting the truncation on the inner `div` (also with `width: inherit`) but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a class to other columns i.e Checkbox, Staff and Client columns and fix their width by giving appropriate widths.

Below is the `HTML` and `CSS` code:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.1" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="bootstrap@3.1.1" data-semver="3.1.1" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.1.1" data-semver="3.1.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th></th>
              <th>Email</th>
              <th class="text-center">Staff</th>
              <th class="text-center">Client</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="text-center other-col">
                <input type="checkbox">
              </td>
              <td class="email-col">
                example@example.com
              </td>
              <td class="text-center other-col">
                yes
              </td>
              <td class="text-center other-col">
                no
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="text-center other-col">
                <input type="checkbox">
              </td>
              <td class="email-col">
                example@example.com
              </td>
              <td class="text-center other-col">
                yes
              </td>
              <td class="text-center other-col">
                no
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="text-center other-col">
                <input type="checkbox">
              </td>
              <td class="email-col">
                example@example.com
              </td>
              <td class="text-center other-col">
                yes
              </td>
              <td class="text-center other-col">
                no
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="text-center other-col">
                <input type="checkbox">
              </td>
              <td class="email-col">
                example@example.com
              </td>
              <td class="text-center other-col">
                yes
              </td>
              <td class="text-center other-col">
                no
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

You can find that an additional class `other-col` is added in the above code.

**CSS**

```
/* Styles go here */
.email-col {
    /*width: 100%;
    min-width: 1px;*/
    max-width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.other-col {
  width:10%;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add style for that cell

```
word-break: break-all;
```

Comment: can you fork and edit the plunker to show this working please? What other values should apply to the cell?